# Does aikau MultiSelectInput support more then one value?

Tags: javascript, dojo, multi-select, aikau

Consider widget config:

```
{
    id: "MyMultiSelect",
    name: "alfresco/forms/controls/MultiSelectInput",
    config: {
        label: "My multi-select input",
        name: "assoc_myGood",
        width: "400px",
        addedAndRemovedValues: true,
        valueDelimiter: ",",
        choiceCanWrap: true,
        choiceMaxWidth: "100%",
        optionsConfig: {
            labelAttribute: "name",
            queryAttribute: "name",
            valueAttribute: "value",
            publishTopic: "ALF_CRUD_GET_ALL",
            publishPayload: {
                url: "/slingshot/datalists/lists/node/workspace/SpacesStore/dc1b9c22-b955-4e5f-9b10-2343680a15f5",
                resultsProperty: "response.datalists"
            },
            searchStartsWith: true
        }
    }
}
```

Values are retrived, but when it comes to select, it possible to select one value but after that all other values become disabled. E.g. only one value can be selected.

So does `MultiSelectInput` support select more then 1 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [MultiSelectInput](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/MultiSelectInput.html) does support the selection of more than one value. See this [live example](https://aikau-sandpit.alfresco.com/aikau-sandpit/page/na/ws/MultiSelectInput) on the Aikau Sandpit. I would suggest that the issue is that your `optionsConfig` is incorrect. Based on your other question I would say that each option is being assigned the same value which is why only one option can be selected.

Comment: My bad, it is needed to change `valueAttribute: "nodeRef"`. I did experiments on Comboboxes and forget to test this variant. :)